# Android drawable folders fallback rule

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to understand how the drawable folders in Android works. I found that in the resource folder in our project, it has the following folders:

```
res/drawable-ldpi/
res/drawable-ldpi-v8/
res/drawable-ldpi-v11/
res/drawable-mdpi/
res/drawable-mdpi-v8/
res/drawable-mdpi-v11/
res/drawable-hdpi/
res/drawable-hdpi-v8/
res/drawable-hdpi-v11/
res/drawable-xhdpi/
res/drawable-xhdpi-v8/
res/drawable-xhdpi-v11/
res/drawable-xxhdpi/
res/drawable-xxhdpi-v8/
res/drawable-xxhdpi-v11/
```

Can someone please educate me on how the fallback mechanism on these folders works? Also what does v8 and v11 mean?

Answer (score 4):

From [Android doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2):

> The API level supported by the device. For example, v1 for API level 1 (devices with Android 1.0 **or higher**) and v4 for API level 4 (devices with Android 1.6 **or higher**). See the Android API levels document for more information about these values.

`-v8` and `-v11` are [API version](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html) but when android will determine the best match to use resource it will use them as "level" (and not strict api version number), e.g. with your project folders structure:

- With device running Froyo (Android 2.2, **API 8**) with **mdpi** screen then resources will be taken from `res/drawable-mdpi-v8/` folder
- With device running Gingerbread (Android 2.3, **API 10**) with **mdpi** screen then resources will also be taken from `res/drawable-mdpi-v8/` folder (because 8<10<11)
- With device running Ice Cream Sandwich (Android 4.0, **API 15**) with **mdpi** screen then resources will also be taken from `res/drawable-mdpi-v11/` folder (because 11<15)

--

Why default res folders are `v-8`, `v-11`,`v-15`... and not `v-12`,`v-13` or `v-16`... ?

Because it was major releases of Android with changes on UI mechanism (e.g. Api 11 was the first Android optimized for tablets).

Answer (score 3):

`-v11` and `-v8` are version qualifiers (you can read more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#QualifierRules)) for version 11 and 8 of android. If your app is running on one of them, then it tries to pick the drawable from the specific folder. If it is not in there, then it tries on the less specific. E.g. you are running and `mdpi` screen on `Honeycomb`, the first attempt is `res/drawable-mdpi-v11/`. If the drawable is not in there, it looks for it in `res/drawable-mdpi/`. The look up continues until the closest drawable to your configuration is found.

Comment: Specifically, **Table 2** on that page is in order of operator precedence and the method for determining the "best match" [is here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#BestMatch).

Comment: If I have api version 16 on the device, does it go to drawable-xxhdpi or drawable-xxhdpi-v11?

Comment: @Blackbelt, it seems that your answer is wrong because according to the doc (see my answer),  drawable-xxhdpi-v11 will be used for device running API level 11 **or higher**.

Comment: @Linghui it'll we try to look it up first in `res/drawable-xxhdpi-v11`